# How to create a glove embeddings?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

Python 3.9.6

There is a GenSym to work with Word2vek, which creates the desired mapping of words into a vector space. As I understand it, Glove is an optimized version of Word2Vec, which exactly converges on a smaller corpus of words. But I didn't find a technique on how to create vector representations of words using a glove.

What is the technique for obtaining glove- vector representations of words for highly specialized literature?

Answer (score 1):

The original implementation, which is the only Stanford NLP one, is in (multi-threaded) C: [stanfordnlp/GloVe](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe).

However more than one person has written a Python implementation, but I can't speak to their quality: e.g., [maciejkula/glove-python](https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python) and [pengyan510/nlp-paper-implementation](https://github.com/pengyan510/nlp-paper-implementation/tree/master/glove).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using zeugma

https://pypi.org/project/zeugma/0.41/

this tool makes implementation really easy

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegresion
from zeugma.embeddings import EmbeddingTransformer

glove = EmbeddingTransformer('glove')
x_train = glove.transform(corpus_train)

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

x_test = glove.transform(corpus_test)
model.predict(x_test)
```